# Display issue with monitor

Tags: video, graphics-card, hardware-failure

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04 on such computer:

```
Kubuntu 18.04 64-bit, CPU Intel E8200, Video GeForce GT 630, Noveau display driver in use.
```

On my monitor I can see different type of rectangles such as:
[image]
[image]

Also I've noticed the blinking rectangles (or lines) with different traceries, you can see them on video (after 10 seconds)

[Video, how it appears on monitor](https://youtu.be/fShARD9xB34)

What kind of problem is this? Is it related to hardware (monitor, videocard) or is it a OS' problem? Thanks

Comment: Maybe video card or video card driver?

Comment: One easy way to test if it's the monitor, or some other hardware issue is to connect a new monitor or TV and see if it still displays strangely.

Comment: @megas Are you using the propietary driver or Noveau?

Comment: @jcbermu It uses Noveua display driver

Comment: @DrZoo But I don't have it right now

Comment: All relevant information should be contained within the question body.  So if you are using the Noveua display driver, that should be stated, in the question body not a comment.

Comment: @megas I suggest to try the propietary drivers following a [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)